# Global variables in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, global-variables

I am creating a jquery plugin. In that am using some global variablse
 `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount: 0` is one of them.

I am assigned some values to this from one function `inside an ajax call`.

```
 callAjax = function (surl, pselector, pi, rec) {
 $.ajax({
 ..
   success: function (data) {
           $.rmtableparams.recordsCount =10;
    }
  });
  }
```

But while I am trying to access `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount` in some other function it returns 0. But strange thing is that if `i alert anything` before that `it will returns 10` correctly.

Ie: if my script is

```
alert("hi");
alert($.rmtableparams.recordsCount);
```

the second alert will shows 10

But if only `alert($.rmtableparams.recordsCount);` is there it returns 0

I was wondered with this. If any body knows the reason please help me.

Comment: Where is `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount` declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount =10;` is inside the `success` callback of an `$.ajax` request. So the value isn't assigned until the ajax call is completed, and a response received. This happens fairly quickly, so while you're first `alert` is waiting to be closed, the ajax response is received, and the assignment is processed. Then, the second alert shows the new value.

If you leave out the first alert, the call is still being processed and the `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount` value hasn't changed yet.
It's as simple as that: AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. Async is key, but often overlooked...

Comment: yes . I tried with `async:false,` in ajax call. Then it is working fine.

Comment: is it make any proble for making the request `synchronous` as i did with `async:false`???

Comment: @Nithesh: Well, then you know the reason, don't you? BTW: `async: false` is _deprecated_ (from the docs: _"As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated;
you must use the complete/success/error callbacks."_). move the alert inside the `success` callback, and the alert will always show 10, but it won't fire until the call is complete

Answer (score 0):

You can't just go ahead and set `$.rmtableparams.recordsCount` because `$.rmtableparams` doesn't exist.

You first need to set `$.rmtableparams`:

```
$.rmtableparams = {};
```

Then you go ahead and add data to the object:

```
$.rmtableparams.recordsCount = 10;
```

Make sure that the success callback is being fired. Add an `alert` or `console.log` inside the callback to do the check.

Comment: already did this. `$.rmtableparams = {
               recordsCount: 0

    };`

Comment: Hmm, okay. Let me think.

Comment: Make sure that the success callback is being called. And check for any errors in a console.

Comment: if i placed any alert inside success it triggers. and rest will be fine then also. Also no errors in console. It is strange that it work perfectly if one alert() is there.

Comment: @Nithesh: A(synchronous)J(avaScript)A(nd)X(ML)... check my answer